# Python sum values in tuple in a list in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

In my dictionary, each entry has a list of tuples (my python grammar may be wrong, please bear with me).  It looks something like this:

```
{1: [(2, 2), (4, 3), (6, 1), (7, 1), (8, 3)], 2: [(4, 1), (5, 3), (1, 2)],...}
```

I'd like to sum the second value in the tuple for each entry, i.e.:

```
{1: (10), 2: (5)...}
```

I have been using different forms of

`result = sum(y for v in dict.itervalues() for (x, y) in v)`

But it adds up all of the values for both entries.

Comment: `{k: sum(x for _, x in v) for k, v in dict.items()}`

Comment: note that the parenthesis on the value doesn't make it a tuple, same as: `{1: 10, 2: 5...}`

Comment: @vaulth nice answer!

Comment: @vaultah, why don't you put this as a real answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

Edit: Thanks to @ vaultah's comment.

```
a = {1: [(2, 2), (4, 3), (6, 1), (7, 1), (8, 3)], 2: [(4, 1), (5, 3), (1, 2)]}
final = {k:(sum(j for _,j in v),) for k,v in a.items()}
print(final)

Output:

>>> {1: (10,), 2: (6,)}
```

Comment: Even assuming that the OP wants to keep the sum in a tuple, it's not worth calling the `tuple` constructor. `(sum(j for _,j in v),)` would work as well.

Comment: Oh yes ! I didn't know that i can do something like this within tuples ! Great comment ! Thanks. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
sum = 0
for item in dict:
    for _,x in dict[item]:
        sum = sum + x
    print sum
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve it using `map/lambda`:

```
result = {k: sum(map(lambda x: x[1], v)) for k, v in dict.items()}
```