# How to aggregate values from a list of tuples and store them in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, tuples

INPUT:

```
list = [("a",1),("b",2),("c",3),("a",4),("b",5),("c",6)]
```

This is the OUTPUT I am looking for:

```
d = {"a":5,"b":7,"c":9}
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43400223/python-sum-values-in-tuple-in-a-list-in-a-dictionary

Comment: remember formatting

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through the list; as a tuple, the first object [0] is your letter, the second [1] is the number. It tries to add the number. If the key isn't created yet (first time seeing the letter) it creates it.

```
d = {}
list = [("a",1),("b",2),("c",3),("a",4),("b",5),("c",6)]



for i in list:
    try:
        d[i[0]] += i[1]
    except KeyError:
        d[i[0]] = i[1]


print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 5, 'b': 7, 'c': 9}
```

Comment: Why the key error: 'a'  when tried without try and except ??

Comment: Because the `+=` operation requires the key to exist in order for it to be added to. The `=` can create the key.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and a loop:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('a', 4), ('b', 5), ('c', 6)]
d = defaultdict(int)

for item in lst:
    d[item[0]] += item[1]

print(dict(d))  # {'a': 5, 'b': 7, 'c': 9}
```

On a side note, don't name your variable `list` to avoid shadowing the [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative without dependencies

```
res_ = {}
for e in mlist:
  if e[0] in res_: res_[e[0]] += e[1]
  else: res_[e[0]] = e[1]

print(res_)
#=> {'a': 5, 'c': 9, 'b': 7}
```

Comment: Can the question be solved using dict.keys()

Comment: You mean `if e[0] in res_.keys():`?